# Lumps after Carpet Stretching

Tags: carpet

We paid to have our carpets stretched by professionals. When they were finished it all looked great to LOOK at.........then after they left I started noticing that there were LUMPS everywhere UNDERNEATH the carpet! Lumps that were NOT there before the carpet was re-stretched. Is this because they allowed the padding to bunch up underneath as the re-stretched the carpet? and I'm guessing this can't be fixed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture or two of the problem? Perhaps with oblique lighting to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about the padding bunching up in highly possible. If the carpet was installed over the pad for some time it may have stuck to the padding in some places leading to the padding being pulled out of position as the carpet was restretched. There are a number of things that could cause carpet to pad adhesion.

1. A carpet backing material inherently incompatible with the type of padding.
2. Environmental conditions that cause the padding to decompose into a sticky goo that pastes to the carpet backing.
3. Hot melt carpet splicing tape where some of the glue oozes out from the edges of the tape and adheres to the padding.
4. Something was spilled on the carpet at one time that bled through the backing and made a sticky mess at the padding but was unable to be fully cleaned from above. Think 'can of soda' or similar.
5. Heavy furniture with legs that caused high pressure point locations that compressed the carpet and padding so tight together over a long period of time that they literally bond together.

Comment: OP was asking about fixes

Comment: @SolarMike - The actual question was "Is this because they allowed the padding to bunch up underneath as the re-stretched the carpet?". So I answered as to the positive and why that can happen. As far as fixes all the OP stated was "I'm guessing this can't be fixed." which is a statement and not a question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed; an installer can pull back and separate any glue between the padding and carpet, re-stretch and re-seam. Possibly the original installer may have just layed the padding with no glue or staples to the subfloor (I've worked for guys who didn't). Preferably talk to the guy who re-stretched because I'd never leave a job like that. Point being its 100% fixable.